# OpenCV only showing a black image when cv.imshow is used

Tags: python, opencv

Hi whenever I use the `cv2.imshow` function all I get is a black rectangle like this:

[image]

My code is here, I am using python:

```
from cv2 import cv2
image = cv2.imread("scren.png")
cv2.imshow("image2", image)
```

I have tried using different file types as well as restarting my computer.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: Add `cv2.waitKey(0)` after `cv2.imshow(...).

Comment: That worked!  Why is WaitKey required for a proper imshow?

Answer (score 0):

I'll put the answer from @fmw42 here as it solved for me too and I was looking for it for some hours

Add `cv2.waitKey(0)` after `cv2.imshow(...)`.

I don't know why it solves, but solved for me.

Comment: It tells imshow to wait for a key press rather than some time when 0 is replaced with x. Without waitKey, it freezes my terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the [imshow](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563) function requires a subsequent command to [waitKey](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7) or else the image will not show. I believe this functionality has to do with how [highgui](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html) works. So to display an image in Python using opencv you will always have to do something like this:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread(r"path\to\image")
cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Note about [imshow](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563)

> This function should be followed by a call to cv::waitKey or cv::pollKey to perform GUI housekeeping tasks that are necessary to actually show the given image and make the window respond to mouse and keyboard events. Otherwise, it won't display the image and the window might lock up. For example, waitKey(0) will display the window infinitely until any keypress (it is suitable for image display). waitKey(25) will display a frame and wait approximately 25 ms for a key press (suitable for displaying a video frame-by-frame). To remove the window, use cv::destroyWindow.

See [also](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dd5/highgui_8hpp.html).